# I'm trying to do state lifting in React. What am I missing?

Tags: reactjs

I'm new to react - literally a couple of days old.
All I'm trying to do is **state lifting**. The state for CreateTweet is to be lifted to App.js which is the root so that the lifted states can be passed onto other components rendered by the root.
Things seem to be in place, but I'm getting the following error:
Uncaught Error: Invalid hook call. Hooks can only be called inside of the body of a function component. This could happen for one of the following reasons:

1. You might have mismatching versions of React and the renderer (such as React DOM)
2. You might be breaking the Rules of Hooks
3. You might have more than one copy of React in the same app
   See https://reactjs.org/link/invalid-hook-call for tips about how to debug and fix this problem.

**App.js**

```
class App extends Component {
    render() {
            
        const [textInput, setTextInput] = useState("");
        const [tweets, setTweets] = useState([]);

        const name = "SomeNameJohnDoe";
        return (
                <div>
                    <h1>Hello React learners!</h1>
                    <CreateTweet
                    textInput={textInput}
                    setTextInput={setTextInput}
                    tweets={tweets}
                    setTweets={setTweets}
                    />
                    <TweetList name={name} tweets={tweets}/>
                </div>
            );
    }
}
```

**CreateTweet.js**

```
function CreateTweet({textInput, setTextInput, tweets, setTweets}){

    const userInputHandler = (e) => {
        setTextInput(e.target.value);
    }
    const submitTweetHandler = (e) => {
        e.preventDefault();
        setTweets([...tweets, textInput]);
        setTextInput("");     
    }
    return(
        <form onSubmit={submitTweetHandler}>
            <textarea value={textInput} onChange={userInputHandler} cols="50" rows="5"></textarea>
            <button>Submit</button>
        </form>
    );
}
```

Thank you for helping me out. Cheers!

Comment: You can not use classes with react hooks.

Comment: React hooks for functional component. Use normal state object for class components - https://levelup.gitconnected.com/react-state-in-class-and-function-components-2269614579c4

Comment: Hello, so if you are trying to lift the state up and planning to have a Global place where you can reply on Data i would suggest using GlobalProvider, and AppReducers, as they are easy to manage if your App gets too BIG

Answer (score 0):

You cannot use classes with react hooks. Simple as that.
More on class and functional components:
https://levelup.gitconnected.com/react-state-in-class-and-function-components-2269614579c4

Answer (score 0):

```
class App extends Component {

 state = {
   textInput: "",
   tweets: ""
 }

 textInputHandler = (val) => {
    this.setState({
        textInput: val       
    })
 }

 tweetsHandler = (val) => {
    this.setState({
        tweets: val       
    })
 }

 name = "SomeNameJohnDoe";

    render() {
        
        return (
                <div>
                    <h1>Hello React learners!</h1>
                    <CreateTweet
                    textInput={this.state.textInput}
                    setTextInput={this.textInputHandler }
                    tweets={this.state.tweets}
                    setTweets={this.tweetsHandler }
                    />
                    <TweetList name={this.name} tweets={this.tweets}/>
                </div>
            );
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
In React you should understand the difference between a functional component and class component. Hooks have been introduced in react 16.8 to compensate the lack of state maganement (useState), lifeCycle (ComponentWillMount, ComponentDidMount,...etc) in Functional component. 
    So every time you are trying to use a hook make sure you have declare a functional Component instead of a class. 
    P.S: a functionnal component is a pure Javascript function.
    So you had 2 ways to implement your Component App 
   
    1)- As a functional Component

    import React, {useState} from 'react';
    const App =(props)=> { //if you are planning to use any props
        const [textInput, setTextInput] = useState("");
        const [tweets, setTweets] = useState([]);
        const name = "SomeNameJohnDoe";  
            return (
                    <div>
                        <h1>Hello React learners!</h1>
                        <CreateTweet
                        textInput={textInput}
                        setTextInput={setTextInput}
                        tweets={tweets}
                        setTweets={setTweets}
                        />
                        <TweetList name={name} tweets={tweets}/>
                    </div>
               );
    }

    2)- As a class Component.

import React from 'react';  
const name = "SomeNameJohnDoe";    
class App extends Component {
    state = {
       textInput: "",
       tweets: ""
    }
    setTextInput = (input) =>{
       this.setState({textInput:input});
    }
    setTweets = (tweet) =>{
        this.setState({tweets:tweet});
    }
    render() {
         return(
              <div>
                  <h1>Hello React learners!</h1>
                  <CreateTweet
                       textInput={this.state.textInput}
                       setTextInput={this.setTextInput}
                       tweets={this.state.tweets}
                       setTweets={this.setTweets}
                   />
                   <TweetList name={name} tweets={this.state.tweets}/>
               </div>
         );
     }
}
```